# How to keep checkbox selection on listview items after adding and sorting?

Tags: java, android, listview

This is a ListView using a multiple choice adapter.

```
public class ExampleActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ListView list;
    private List<String> items;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_example);
        this.list = this.getListView();
        this.items = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.items.add("A");
        this.items.add("C");
        this.items.add("D");
        this.items.add("D");
        this.adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, items);
        this.list.setAdapter(adapter);

        this.user(); // simulating user selecting C

        this.button(); // simulating user press some button who adds items to list
    }

    private void user() {
        this.list.setItemChecked(1, true);
    }

    private void button() {
        this.items.add("B");
        Collections.sort(this.items);
        this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

If user selects C (index 1), and if then user press button to add items to list and sort (like B), B (new index 1) is going to be selected instead of C.
How can this issue be solved?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you make selection for index **1**

```
 this.list.setItemChecked(1, true); // selects C
```

and after make the insertion and sort , `B` is the item with index `1`

try this

```
this.list.setItemChecked(this.list.indexOf("c"),true);
```

Comment: Thank you, although I think my question was not explicit, edited now.